# Rewritting square root of non integer as a recurrence with integral coefficients.

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

Let's say we have a number $q \in \Bbb Q-\Bbb Z$, and we take the square root of it: $\sqrt q$.

When is it possible to write $\sqrt q$ in the form$$a_1=c_1+b_1\sqrt[k_1]{a_0}$$ $$a_n=c_n+b_n\sqrt[k_n]{a_{n-1}}$$

For integers $n,b_n,c_n,k_n,a_0$?

Comment: It is never possible to write $\sqrt{q}$ in either form. This is because $\sqrt{q}$ is a number, whereas the two "forms" are both equations. Numbers and equations are two different things. Perhaps you could clarify what you mean?

Comment: Yes, what I meant is: "When does there exist a natural $i$ such that $\sqrt q=a_i$?". Does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

With integer coefficients, taking nested radicals preserves the property of being an algebraic integer.  Square roots of non-integer rational numbers are not algebraic integers, so what you ask (if I interpret the question correctly) is not possible.

If you mean, "what are the relations between nested radicals over $\mathbb{Q}$", I don't think there is any theory to detect those other than computing minimal polynomials and testing for a common zero.  If you want real radicals then further testing is needed to see if a potential solution comes from a real solution, which is likewise a computational task with relatively little theory (inequalities, simple Galois theory) to provide guidance.

Comment: I see, that's pretty sad. I think you've understood my question correctly (perhaps a clearer way to phrase it would be "Does the recurrence $a_n$ take square root of non-integer rationals values?", which is what I think you've responded). Could you elaborate a bit on why does the nesting of radicals preserve the algebraic integrality (if that's a word)?

Comment: If $u$ is an algebraic integer then so is the solution of $x^n - u$.  Sums and products of algebraic integers are also algebraic integers.  And the ordinary integers are algebraic integers.  This is all you need for the recurrence.

Comment: (That was mentioned in the answer.  @PaulSinclair )

Comment: Sorry. Skimmed it too lightly...